# SUBSTRING(CITY,-1) and SUBSTRING(CITY,-1,1) returns the same output (MySQL) - why?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates (MySQL)

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

[image: Table]

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude

I have written these simple queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE SUBSTRING(CITY,-1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE SUBSTRING(CITY,-1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
```

Both of them work fine, although the syntax of substring should be `SUBSTRING(string, start, length)`

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: RTM - `length` is optional and if omitted, returns the rest of the string from `start`, if you're starting at `-1` (one from the end) the length is implicitly `1`.

Comment: @DaleK , Thanks for notifying me , since this is my first Question , I might have created some mistakes while posting, Please excuse me for that !
Thanks

Comment: You can also use the `RIGHT()` function to get a substring counting from the end.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) It clearly says that the third argument is optional.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM...`, to make code clearer!

Comment: The use of `varchar2` seems to indicate you are actually using Oracle, not MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the length is for what's on the right side of the start position.

The syntax

> SUBSTRING(string, start, length) OR SUBSTRING(string FROM start FOR
> length)
>
> **start** – The starting position. If it is a positive number, this
> function extracts from the beginning of the string. If it is a
> negative number, this function extracts from the end of the string.
>
> **length** – It is optional. It identifies the number of characters to extract.
> If it is not given The whole string is returned from the
> starting position.

So if the length isn't given, then it's the remaining characters till the end of the string.

Then:

```
select substring('abcdef',-3, 2)
```

Starts at the 4th position `d` for length 2
It returns `de`

And:

```
select substring('abcdef',-3)
```

Starts at the 4th position `d` for the remainder of the string
It returns `def`

Hence

```
select substring('abcdef', -1)
```

and

```
select substring('abcdef', -1, 1)
```

both return `f`

And so does

```
select right('abcdef', 1)
```